# Multiple tables share one model class in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, ebean

I am using Playframework 2.1.0 to build a simple web application.

Now I get one question:

I have about 20 tables in my database with names like AB, DF, HD, ER, etc. For some reasons, their table formats are exactly same, and I cannot just use one table to store them. I will just use a specific table in one time.

So can I just write one model class to indicate the table format of those tables? How?

If I can, how should I write the code to map the model class to one specific table in my database dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can write one abstract superclass with all column mappings like that:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractModel {
    protected int id;
    protected String property1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "prop1")
    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }

    public void setProperty1(String property1) {
         this.property1 = property1;
    }
}
```

And then write concrete models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AB")
public class AB extends AbstractModel {
    //some additional fields if you wish
    private String property2;

    @Column(name = "prop2")
    public String getProperty2() {
        return property2;
    }

    public void setProperty2(String property2) {
         this.property2 = property2;
    }
   //additional code here
}
```

So all the field mappings should be inherited.
Hope this helps